# Rails: undefined method error not fixable with attr_accessor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, attr

I have created a very simple model called Discussion and one of the columns is a boolean called resolved.  The idea being that once a discussion item has been resolved that value is set to true.

On the edit form, I tried to put in some logic based on the value of that field.

```
<%= form_for(@discussion) do |d| %>
    ...
<% if d.resolved == "true" %>
    <p>The discussion is resolved</p>
<% else %>
    <p>The discussion is not resolved</p>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

However, I'm getting an error message

```
undefined method `resolved' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000101674678>
```

I tried adding an attr_accessor line to my model but that didn't do anything for me either.  I'm not sure what I have to do to fix this.  I'm pretty new to rails, so I'm sure that whatever the problem is it's probably pretty simple to fix, but I just don't get it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because d represent an instance of the form builder, you want

```
<% if @discussion.resolved %>
```

If resolved is represented as a "boolean" in ActiveRecord.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I would add that mikhailov's answer below was also helpful for me since I didn't know that the ? functions were generated automatically for boolean columns.

Answer (score 3):

every boolean column represents as predicate, so you can use:

```
if @discussion.resolved?
...
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is the resolved? method.

```
<% if @discussion.resolved? %>
```

which is auto-generated for boolean columns.